# TypeScript type inference on function type parameter based on its argument type

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I'm trying to have a function `fun` declared in TypeScript that uses its type parameter `T` as a constraint for what keys can be used as a parameter of another function `context.Foo`:

```
interface Context<T> {
    Foo(key: keyof T)
}

function fun<T>(provider: (context: Context<T>) => T): number {
    return 1
}

fun<{a: number}>(context => {
    return {a: context.Foo('a')}
})
```

So far so good, I can only use 'a' literal as a `key` parameter of `context.Foo` in the `foo` invocation at the bottom, because this invocation has a type parameter that declares `T` to be `{a: number}`.

What bothers me is that I actually define the structure of this type inline as a `provider` function body. I can only return an object that matches `{a: number}` definition.

What I'd like to achieve is to get rid of the need to explicitly define the `T` type of `fun` at invocation time and let type inference figure this type out by itself by the structure of the object I'm returning from the `fun`'s parameter (that is required to be `T`), like this:

```
fun(context => {
    return {a: context.Foo('a')}
})
```

Unfortunately, this ends with an error:

> TS2345: Argument of type '"a"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

Type inference for `T` failed and have fallen back to `never` which is definitely not useful in this case.

Is it possible to define this function in such a way that explicit setting of `fun`'s `T` is not needed?

Comment: What's the return type of `Context.Foo`? Is it always the same type or is it generic?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, even with the up-coming `infer`.

Comment: @fathyb It might be the same type, say `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think is any way to achieve this, as soon as you try to tie `Context<T>` to the keys of the result, the compiler gives up in inference.

Since `Foo` always returns the same value type (at least from what I understood in the comments) you could specify just the keys of the type, and not have to specify the whole type:

```
interface Context<K> {
    Foo(key: K): number;
}

function fun<K extends string>(provider: (context: Context<K>) => Record<K, number>): Record<K, number> {
    return provider(null as any);
}

let a = fun<'a'>(context => {
    return { a: context.Foo('a') }
})
```